# Change WordPress admin URL wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, customization

I have changed WordPress admin URL wp-login to wp-custom and it is working fine but the issue is that when I click on logout it shows me an error. how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: You can do this by using the plugin - 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-wp-admin-login/.

Comment: Is there any custom solution for this??

Comment: You can try these steps - it helps you to do it without the plugin.
https://www.grapestree.com/how-to-change-wordpress-admin-url-wordpress-login-url-wordpress-wp-admin-url-with-without-plugin